# Python SimpleHTTPServer: Cannot connect from any machine on the LAN

Tags: networking, lan, website, http, webserver

I'm trying to view a website I am building on my Mac on an iPad that is connected on the same LAN on the same Wireless AP.

I've got the right IP address, I can load up the page just fine on the same machine (http://localhost)

and this is how I started the server `sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`

What are the steps I can take to figure out why connections from other machines on my network don't work?

Comment: Have you figured out what the exact problem was ? I am facing the same problem at the moment and found this very old question

Comment: The question is too old and not specific for me to remember what I was doing so I do not remember what the resolution was. But it sounds like if you have a third unix computer you can use traceroute etc. like the answer says.

Answer (score 4):

Check if your system and switch firewall is allowing port 80.
Here is what you should do to figure it out from a remote machine in your network:

```
$ traceroute <IP_on_which_python_server_is_running>
```

Also try:

```
$ telnet <IP_on_which_python_server_is_running> 80
```

This will help you to figure out if the port is accessible or not.

Comment: Ah, yes, `traceroute` and `telnet`. good tools that I have used before but forgot about yesterday.

Comment: Could you please upvote this if it helped you. :)